# Replace a column in a text file which has variouse spaces between columns

Tags: java

I have a text file which contains 20 000 lines. data which are in it as columns. But spaces between columns are different and column length also different. Ex

```
aaaaa ()()()()()bdo()()()()()()()()  ttttt ()() dgee ()()()()()  yyyy

bbb()()()()()()()ggg ()()()()()()()(  fff()()()(gbe()()()()()()( yHH

cc()()()()()()()()dddd()()()()()()() I ()()()()bdeg()()()()()()yyyyy
```

here spaces represent from brackets
Like that!!!

I want to replace N th (ex: 4th ) column with the specific word (ex: "name" )

example out put :

```
aaaaa ()()()()()bdo()()()()()()()()  ttttt ()() name ()()()()()  yyyy

bbb()()()()()()()ggg ()()()()()()()(  fff()()()(name()()()()()()( yHH

cc()()()()()()()()dddd()()()()()()() I ()()()()name()()()()()()yyyyy
```

here spaces represent from brackets
can anyone help me on this ?

Comment: In java or scripting will do?

Comment: Do you have any code that you've tired?

Comment: Note: SO is not a code writing service.  Please show us what you've tried so we can help you with specific issues.

Comment: No I don't have any code. I m just trying to figure out but I can't deal with the various spaces thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void replaceColumn(int column, String word, File file) throws IOException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(file);
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = in.nextLine();
        line = line.trim();
        String columns = line.split(" ");
        columns[column] = word;
        line = arrayToString(columns, " ");
        out.println(line);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}

//Helper method
private static String arrayToString(Object[] array, String separator) {
    if (array.length == 0) {
        return "";
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Object element : array) {
        sb.append(element);
        sb.append(separator);
    }
    sb.delete(sb.length - separator.length(), sb.length());
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Hello Michal !thank you so much for the replay but This doesnt give any out put . This code just erase the whole text file and doesnt write anything back to the file . can you please check that again ?